# How to padding the content of a block in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

I search the internet and get a nice redefinition of the block environment of beamer.
It has the ability to set the width of the block, instead of always spanning the whole page.

```
\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][0.95\textwidth]{
  \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{#1}
      \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
        \begin{actionenv}#3
          \def\insertblocktitle{#2}
          \par
          \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
    {\par
          \usebeamertemplate{block end}
        \end{actionenv}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{center}
}
```

Now I want to add padding to the text inside the block. Please notice only text not block title. I want to do this because I am using a plain theme, which does not have the color background to get them easily distinguishable.

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Note that the `minipage` already sets `\textwidth` to its width argument. Setting it again will give you funny results: an argument like `0.95\textwidth` will result in final `\textwidth` of  `0.95*0.95\textwidth`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what the above definition is doing that the already defined `columns` environment doesn't...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{This is a headline}
        This is a block
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{}
      This is another block
    \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I've added a colour theme just to illustrate the extent of the blocks. So the question is: "How can I make the width of the body text thinner than that of the headline?" You can do that  with a `quote` environment inside the block:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{This is a headline}
        \begin{quote}
          Here is some text that is shrunk a little bit isn't it?
        \end{quote}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{}
      This is another block
    \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: quote inside block inside column]

Comment: Thanks for your response. This solution does work well, but the codes look a bit tedious. What I wish is a predefined environment, centered, with adjustable width and nice looking padding.

Comment: @chuan you could try just putting a `quote` inside the environment definition you found?