# How to to set a padding around the page body, draw a frame/border around it, and then add some margin?

Tags: margins, framed

What if I want to set a padding around the page body (on all pages), draw a frame/border around it, and then add some margin?

The `geometry` package doesn't seem to have an option for this among its basic options because it doesn't separate padding and margin.

(I'm asking this question about the whole page body, rather than [about a box explicitly coded in the sources](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23764/3463).

I'm dealing with LaTeX.)

What I want to achieve -- each page is printed like this:

```
>outer margin< | >left<  >mpwidth< >text body< >right< | >outer margin<
               |                     ......            |
               |                    Text text          |         
               |         marginpar  Text text          |         
               |                    Text text          |         
               |                     ......            |
```

Then, I'd also like to change the color of the frame depending on the text (with a command from the text). The frame/border style could be fancier than just a plain rule/line. The piece inside the frame is like a complete customizable page layout: a custom left margin width, a custom right margin width, and a custom marginpar width. This doesn't cross the frame. The frame is at a fixed distance from the edge of the paper ("outer margin").

Comment: [`tikzpagenodes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) provides hooks into locations around the page for drawing a frame. What do you mean by "[adding] some margin"?

Comment: Can you upload a small picture showing what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hmm, actually, there have been almost identical questions (some of them with good answers): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/801/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-borders-around-a-page-in-latex?rq=1 , http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15052/draw-true-page-border , http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73480/how-to-set-colored-ruled-margins-for-different-pages , http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97594/put-a-frame-around-all-pages-except-one-in-a-book , http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73611/3463 , http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57444/3463 , http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18851/3463

Comment: @Werner By "adding margin" I meant giving an explict value for the margin between the frame/border and the edge of the paper.

Comment: @Marco I've plotted the layout I'm talking about.

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev: If one of the questions you linked answers your question, feel free to cast the first close vote.

Comment: @Werner Perhaps, I'll try to make use of some of the methods mentioned there first.

Answer (score 3):

I think the package `background` in combination with `tikzpagenodes` is a good choise.

As a starting point you can use:

[Add background colour to margin notes area](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118792/add-background-colour-to-margin-notes-area/118811#118811)

However there is one disclaimer. The package `background` can change the color of the frame only for the whole page.

Here an example where you can control the distance between the frame and the text by the new two dimensions `\xinnersep` and `\yinnersep`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\xinnersep}
\setlength{\xinnersep}{1.5cm}
\newlength{\yinnersep}
\setlength{\yinnersep}{0.5cm}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
contents={%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[blue,line width=2pt,] ([xshift=-\xinnersep,yshift=\yinnersep]current page text area.north west) --
                                             ([xshift=\xinnersep,yshift=\yinnersep]current page text area.north east) -- 
                                             ([xshift=\xinnersep,yshift=-\yinnersep]current page text area.south east) -- 
                                             ([xshift=-\xinnersep,yshift=-\yinnersep]current page text area.south west) -- cycle;
 \end{tikzpicture}%
}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This almost works (yshift caused some problem, but I actually don't need it: the whole rectangle appeared below the bottom...)

Comment: Could you please tell me what the bettrr way woulf be to select a different color in the middle of the document? (For whole pages.)

Comment: One more problem I encountered: it produces strange wrong border lines on non-complete pages before `\clearpage` Is this a known and understood problem? Not always, but sometimes.

Comment: The problem can be seen at https://gitorious.org/primary-school-informatics-problems/2013_mathinf/trees/BUG/tex-some-crazy-borders_/VIEW in 1_klass.pdf produced from 1_klass.tex